# How to disable JavaScript in browser using Selenium (Java)?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In my feature automation, I need to disable JavaScript in browser and run the flow. How to disable JavaScript?

Tried DesiredCapabilities for firefox and Chrome.

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT, false)
```

And

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setJavascriptEnabled(false);
```

For firefox, tried 
1) Setting up profile for firefox

2) Adding add-on - noScript.xpi

3) profile.setPreference("javascript.enabled", false);

4) Through UI, tried changing the flag - "javascript.enabled" in "about:config" to false. Here, opened firefox and gave "about:config" getting a warning - "This might void your warranty!". There is a button - "I'll be careful, I promise!" with id - warningButton. This button should be clicked to proceed further. To click this button, used driver.findElement(By.id("warningButton")).click(); but it not work.

All the above options are not working. Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51681608/2248627) works for `Firefox 61.0.1`

Comment: [option simpler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53054654/7685008) than the one above. work for modern versions of firefox

Answer (score 5):

I don't know Java, but maybe a solution for Python 3 will help you.

in Python, you can use Options() instead of FirefoxProfile() to deactivate JavaScript:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options()
options.preferences.update({"javascript.enabled": False})
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('about:config')
```

Maybe Java this:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.preferences.update({"javascript.enabled": False});
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.get('about:config')
```

Comment: I am using selenium-java version 3.141.0 and 
      options.addPreference("javascript.enabled", false);    //works

Answer (score 2):

You change the preference value using profile with lots of options:

```java
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
// setCapability(SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT, javascriptEnabled);
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(false);

FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary( new File( binaryPath ) );
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

//profile.setPreference("preferenceName", "Value");
profile.setPreference("javascript.enabled", false);

RemoteWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile, capabilities);
```

To view the preferences, you can visit the `URL about:config`

[image]

@See

- [Chrome driver to disable JavaScript issue](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3175)
- [chromium-command-line-switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Comment: This code works now for firefox,public void testDisableJS() throws Exception {
  WebElement element;
  driver.get("about:config");
  driver.findElement(By.id("warningButton")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
  element = driver.findElement(By.id("warningButton"));
  Actions act = new Actions(driver);
  act.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
  act.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).sendKeys("javascript.enabled").perform();
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  act.sendKeys(Keys.TAB).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).perform();
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  driver.get("https://www.google.com");
 }

Answer (score 1):

As per *Selenium 3.6 Java Client Release*, the easiest way to disable `Javascript` in the browser would be to set the **`setJavascriptEnabled`** argument through an instance of `DesiredCapabilities` to **`False`** and merge it through an instance of `FirefoxOptions` as follows:

```
package demo;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class Q46883024_setJavascriptEnabled 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dc.setJavascriptEnabled(false);
        FirefoxOptions op = new FirefoxOptions();
        op.merge(dc);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(op);
        driver.get("https://google.com");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

> While execution, the browser you are using may override the `setJavascriptEnabled` settings.

Comment: @Saravana On StackOverflow we say **`Thanks`** by **`Accepting`** the best **`Answer`** and by **`Upvoting`** the **`Answers`** which helped in solving your question.

Comment: Got it @DebanjanB, will follow in the future conversions

Comment: the selenium version which i use is not supporting FirefoxOptions(), guessing it should be upgraded. So unable to try this option. Also not want to upgrade now. Will definitely try this option after upgrade.

Comment: Yeap, that's why my Answer stats with `Selenium 3.6 Java Client Release` but you haven't mentioned your `Selenium` version.

Answer (score 1):

Truse me this was random trial but works perfectly for me

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options= webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_prefs = {}
options.experimental_options["prefs"] = chrome_prefs
chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = {"javascript": 2}
chrome_prefs["profile.managed_default_content_settings"] = {"javascript": 2}
driver = webdriver.Chrome("your chromedriver path here",options=options)

driver.get('https://google.com/search?q=welcome to python world')
```

Example image here:-https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdKZQ.png

Comment: Question: "javascript": 2 .... what does the number 2 means? Disable? And what would 0, 1, 3 ,4,.... mean?

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();      
options.addPreference("javascript.enabled", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it for Chrome in Java.

```
// import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-agent=\"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)\"");
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.javascript", 2);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
new ChromeDriver(options);
```

And it worked for me with `ChromeDriver 2.41.578706`. As a bonus I am also setting `Googlebot` as user-agent.

In case you need to do something with `DesiredCapabilities` you can also convert the options above to capabilities:

```
// import static org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY;

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(CAPABILITY, options);
new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```