# How to Disable Javascript in Chrome (-headless) using PHP Webdriver

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, selenium, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Chrome headlessly.

I tried setting the `--disable-javascript` command line argument.

I tried using the experimental options:

```
        $options->setExperimentalOption('prefs', [
            'profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript' => 2//this does not work
            //,'profile.default_content_setting_values.javascript' => 2//this does not work, too
        ]);

        $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
        $capabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);
```

As of this point these two do not work.

How can I disable javascript in Chrome using the Facebook PHP Webdriver ?

Here is a test to check if JavaScript is enabled:

```
        $this->driver->get('https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/is-javascript-enabled');
        return [
            $this->driver->getTitle(),
            $this->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('.detected_result'))->getText()
        ];
```

Comment: Check this [**Discussion/QA -how to disable Java script in browser using java selenium automation?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46883024/how-to-disable-java-script-in-browser-using-java-selenium-automation/46886271#46886271)

Comment: I tried your example with the preferences and javascript is disabled as expected (Win10, Chromium 62, driver 2.33). Another one is `'profile.content_settings.exceptions.javascript.*.setting' => 2`. Make sure that you don't have any policies (`chrome://policy/`) overriding your prefs.

Comment: Thanks @FlorentB. for checking it on Windows. It's good to know it works. It's been almost a month since I starded using Firefox instead. I only have a single Seelenium set up at the moment (Ubuntu 16.04 Vagrant box ). I will spin some Ubuntu 16.04 up with GUI to check the default `chrome://policy/` later. Is it possible that there are some default `proxy` policy settings on a fresh Chrome install ? I mean ... it's a fresh non-X11 install, fresh Chrome install, running the browser headlessly .... and none of these settings work. I am left with trying the `*` one. Will write later ...

Comment: @Boris D. Teoharov, disabling JavaScript is currently not supported when Chrome is launched headlessly. According to this ticket it doesn't load the preferences: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=775911#c7

Comment: @FlorentB. it seems this answers my question. Please, add an answer below so I can give you the bounty prize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to disable the execution of Javascript by setting one of the these preferences :

```
"webkit.webprefs.javascript_enabled": false
"profile.content_settings.exceptions.javascript.*.setting": 2
"profile.default_content_setting_values.javascript": 2
"profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript": 2
```

But it's **currently not supported headlessly** since this mode [doesn't load the preferences](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=775911#c7) and there's no [command switch](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/headless/app/headless_shell_switches.cc) related to this feature.

Note that disabling JavaScript used to break Selenium since most of commands are atom scripts injected in the page. It's no longer the case. All the commands are able to run. However I noticed that the returned text doesn't include the text from a `<noscript>` element (text displayed only when JavaScript is disabled). One workaround is to read the [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) property with either `execute_script` or `get_attribute`.

Answer (score 4):

It is simply impossible. Read here http://yizeng.me/2014/01/08/disable-javascript-using-selenium-webdriver/

> WARNING: Running without JavaScript is unsupported and will likely break a large portion of the ChromeDriver's functionality. I suspect you will be able to do little more than navigate to a page. This is NOT a supported use case, and we will not be supporting it.
>       Closing this as WontFix - the ChromeDriver (and every other WebDriver implementation I'm aware of) require JavaScript to function.

Comment: Is there fresher info on this matter ?

Comment: I am afraid that information is still accurate. I searched the Chromedriver docs and there is no reference on how to disable JS. I also checked the chrome flags but there isn't an option anymore to disable JS via command line.

Comment: This information is no longer accurate. It possible to drive Chrome with Selenium with JavaScript disabled in the page. Scripts (atoms) injected by selenium still work and it's also possible to run your own script with `execute_script`. It is however not supported at this time by the headless mode.

Answer (score 1):

Although regular headless mode in Chrome prevents disabling JavaScript, there's a newer headless mode without restrictions.

The Chromium developers recently added a **2nd** headless mode that functions the same way as normal Chrome.

The NEW way: `--headless=chrome`

The OLD way: `--headless`

There's more info on that here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c36

This means that you can now disable JavaScript when using the newer headless mode.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed, it is still NOT possible to disable JavaScript in Chrome when headless.

However, for future reference, this is how you do it (when you are NOT using the `--headless` argument):

```
        $options = new ChromeOptions();

        $options->setExperimentalOption('prefs', [
            'profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript' => 2,
        ]);

        $result = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();

        $result->setCapability(
            ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY_W3C,
            // There is a bug in php-webdriver, so ->toArray() is needed!
            $options->toArray()
        );
```